# query to get column values based on values of another table i.e,one table values having as field names in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table hrm_m_allowance,pay_m_allowance.

hrm_m_allowance having fields like...

```
INT_APPID       INT_BASIC  A0001 A0002 A0003 A0004 A0005
---------------------------------------------------------
14              7900       1200  700   2000  1000   500
```

pay_m_allowance having fields like...............

```
CHR_ACODE  CHR_ANAME  CHR_BONUS .......etc
----------------------------------------------
A0001       HRA        0
A0002       DA         0
A0003       PF         0
A0004       ESI        0
```

Now I have to get values like

```
BASIC    7900
HRA      1200     
DA        700
PF       2000
ESI      1000
```

Please help me how to get values like above using mysql query

Comment: Is there a field to connect both tables?

Comment: Yes actually I have to join another table hrm_m_offerletter. hrm_m_offerletter,hrm_m_allowance having common fields INT_APPID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funky database design.  I would suggest unpivoting the data first and then doing the `join`:

```
select coalesce(pb.chr_aname, col) as chr_aname, h.val
from (select 'INT_BASIC' as col, INT_BASIC as val from hrm_m_allowance union all
      select 'A0001' as col, A0001 as val from hrm_m_allowance union all
      select 'A0002' as col, A0002 as val from hrm_m_allowance union all
      select 'A0003' as col, A0003 as val from hrm_m_allowance union all
      select 'A0004' as col, A0004 as val from hrm_m_allowance union all
      select 'A0005' as col, A0005 as val from hrm_m_allowance
     ) h left join
     pay_m_allowance pb
     on pb.chr_acode = h.col;
```

One caveat with this approach:  it will work best when all the columns have the same data type.